# asp.net mvc cookies not persisting on local server (aspnetserve)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, persist

Trying to run an MVC app on the 'portable' web server. Software is aspnetserve. (http://www.ohloh.net/p/aspNETserve)

Cookies do not persist. They do fine when I run from visual studio debug. Code is fine, seemingly.

Only are dead (fail to persist from page to page) when I use this server.

My solution requires deploying a portable local solution like this for the app.  (this isn't just being done for purposes of testing)

Rather stumped right now. Any bright ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Could you look at the requests in fiddler. See if you are receiving cookies? In addition, do you have any special attributes set like requiressl, cookie path etc?

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Interesting. My code still finds the cookie to be null -- or any session for that matter... cookie problems causing my session problems, I believe -- however fiddler shows the cookie. And a persistent asp.net session ID. It would seem, according to fiddler, that they ought to be working.

They seem to be there... but accessing them results in null values. Puzzling.

Comment: I realize it works fine on your dev box. Stii, what cookie are you trying to read? How are you trying to read it?

Comment: I was surprised fiddler showed the cookie persisting considering my problems.    How I'm testing:

    if (Request.Cookies["testcookie"] == null)
    {
        Response.Cookies["testcookie"].Value = "test";
        Response.Cookies["testcookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    }

and on another page, check for its existence:

    if (Request.Cookies["testcookie"] == null)
        Response.Write("bad");
    else
        Response.Write("good");

Launch from VS.. fine, returns "good". Run on aspnetserve, returns "bad."

Sessions are the same deal.

Comment: ..and you have tried this from different browsers? Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari?

Comment: yes, have tried on different browsers. Most of my testing is done on chrome. (default browser)

Comment: Any configuration settings that get changed when you move to the production server?

Comment: Try using a script like this on the server. See if you are able to set/read cookies. See section on :
Create cookie
Read cookie
Erase cookie

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Turn on tracing on the page. See the listing of cookies. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx